# Join 3 tables without losing ability to refer each table

Tags: sqlite, left-join

I have 3 tables with this mock data

```
Item *id, name*
1, coke
2, fanta 
3, juice

Branch *id, name*
1, store
2, warehouse
3, shop

BranchItem *item_id, branch_id, qty*
1, 1, 100
1, 2, 30
2, 2, 10
```

I want to query for an item(coke for example) and get its quantity in all branches( even the ones it doesn't exist in, those should have NULL for *qty* column)

So the result should look like

```
1, coke, store, 100

1, coke, warehouse, 30

1, coke, shop, NULL
```

I have a query that can do this, but because of aliasing tables, I lose the ability to refer to the column of the result table. The parsing of the result is done in an ORM object which preferably shouldn't be rewritten

The query I have

```
Select * from item left join (select * from branch left join ( select * from branchitem where item_id = 1) branchitem on branch.id = branchitem.branch_id) JOINEDNAME on true where item.id = 1;
```

My question is I don't want to Elias the join of branch and brunch item as I lose the ability to refer to them separately in the ORM. How can this query be re-written so the tables retain their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use subqueries:

```
SELECT Item.id,
       Item.name,
       Branch.name,
       BranchItem.qty
FROM Item
CROSS JOIN Branch
LEFT JOIN BranchItem ON Item.id = BranchItem.item_id
                    AND Branch.id = BranchItem.branch_id
WHERE Item.id = 1;  -- or put it into the branch join
```